# Specify address for transaction in truffle test

Tags: truffle, ethereumjs, truffle-contract, truffle-test

I want to specify the address I perform a transaction with in my truffle test.

My test looks approximately like this:

```
contract('Test contract', async (accounts) => {

    let contract;

    before(async () => {
        contract = await Contract.new();
    });

    it("Check something...", async () => {
        await studentV1.addPerson("Jon", "Doe");
        await studentV1.addPerson("Max", "Musterman");

        //....
    });
});
```

The contract methode `addPerson(...)` works approximately like this:

```
function addPerson(string _firstname, string _lastname) public {
    persons[msg.sender] = Person(_firstname, _lastname);
}
```

Now I want to call my test at `await studentV1.addPerson("Jon", "Doe");` with `account[0]` and the line below with `account[1]` so my map will also get two different entries. How can I do this? By default truffle test uses for each transaction and call `accounts[0]`.

Im working with the `truffle develop` chain which automatically creates 10 accounts on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the general formula to call a method using an account i :

```
await contract.yourFuncitonName(arg1,arg2,{ from: accounts[i] })
```

notice s at the end of accounts[]

you end up with :

```
 await studentV1.addPerson("Jon", "Doe",{ from: accounts[0] });
 await studentV1.addPerson("Max", "Musterman",{ from: accounts[1] });
```